# Running webpack works but WebStorm reports error

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webstorm, webpack

WebStorm reports error on an untouched fork of [Angular 2 webpack boilerplate](https://github.com/shprink/angular2-nobullshit-boilerplate), see image below. Error message is for App in the line `import {App} from './components/index';` in the file [lib/index.ts](https://github.com/shprink/angular2-nobullshit-boilerplate/blob/master/lib/index.ts) and says `Corresponding file is not included in tsconfig.json`. But executing `webpack-dev-server` gives no errors and the app runs nicely in the browser.

If I remove the following from [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/shprink/angular2-nobullshit-boilerplate/blob/master/tsconfig.json):

```
"files": [
  "lib/index.ts"
]
```

then the error is gone. The app also runs fine (also after stopping and starting `webpack-dev-server`), but just before the `webpack: bundle is now VALID.` there are many errors all saying `... error TS2300: Duplicate identifier ...`, but as mentioned, the app works fine.

How to fix this to make both WebStorm and webpack happy?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I found the solution myself.

I removed the same lines of code in tsconfig.js as in the question, but added instead

```
"exclude": [ "node_modules" ]
```

Then everybody is happy :)